# Localhost vs. 0.0.0.0

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had problems troubleshooting IP addresses with my setup and want to verify some questions, if you could help:

1. Should I use **localhost** or **0.0.0.0** when referring to myself, or does it have to be a real URI?
2. I have read that if you don't have a DNS name, you must use ROS_IP and not ROS_HOSTNAME, yet I see many examples where an ip address is used for ROS_HOSTNAME. For example, here: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/#network-configuration near the end you will see ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.9.100
3. Can I omit both ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME usually - unless I have more than one network adapter. If I have more than one then by default ROS would use all of them. But by specifying ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME I can limit ROS to a specific one.

#### Followup

1. On the computer running ROSCORE, I understand that this is almost always sufficient.

`export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311`

Under what special circumstances does that computer need a specific IP address of ROS_MASTER? And does it ever need ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297713/localhost-vs.-0.0.0.0/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-17**:
Do you have links for these examples?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-17**:
You can use either `ROS_IP` or `ROS_HOSTNAME`. If you have both set, `ROS_HOSTNAME` will take precedence. See https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-17**:
Here's one example specifying an IP address with ROS_HOSTNAME: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/#network-configuration (you have to look for it near the end of that page.)

Also what about localhost vs. 0.0.0.0?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-17**:
That tutorial that you linked to is incorrect. `ROS_HOSTNAME` is for hostnames such as `localhost`, not IP addresses as that's what `ROS_IP` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll answer your question to best of my ability.

- From this [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/949522), you should stick with `localhost`:

> - `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address (also known as localhost).
> - `0.0.0.0` is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target (a no particular address placeholder).

- That [tutorial that you linked to](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/#network-configuration) is incorrect. `ROS_HOSTNAME` is for hostnames such as `localhost`, not IP addresses as that's what ROS_IP is for.
- You can [use either `ROS_IP` or `ROS_HOSTNAME`](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME). If you have both set, `ROS_HOSTNAME` will take precedence.

As for the bottom line, it's a matter of preference as to which to use. I prefer `ROS_HOSTNAME` because I can use it in launch files in the `<machine>` tag and it's easier to remember hostnames vs. IP addresses.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-22**:
Thanks! Please check the followup question in the original post under "followup"? Thanks!!!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-22**:
I'll take a look at it if you post it as a new question. You can provide a link back to this question keep the continuity